# How to put timeline box in the middle?

Tags: html, css

I have a time line codes [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xmbohx/dnwgqmf7/10/)

```
<div class="bungkus center">
<div class="timeline">
<div class="checkpointt">End
</div>
```

the CSS :

```
.checkpointt {
    max-width: 14em;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 0.5px solid #888;
    padding: 5px;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 50px;
}
```

And I wish I can move the start and end button box aligned center to the line

[image: as follow]

I cant find where I miss :(
Please advise

Comment: Please post your code a [repro]. Questions must be self-containing and not solely relay on an external Codepen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do 2 things below

```
.checkpointt {
max-width: 14em;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 6px;
border: 0.5px solid #888;
padding: 5px;
z-index: 1;
left: 50px; // this should be 0, or remove it
margin: auto; // Add this one
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try add "margin: 0 auto;" to the .checkpointt, I think the left and right margins are set to "auto" :)
Also, the problem might be the parent container, make sure the parent div has a width set to 100%, also the position: relative; property in your .checkpointt CSS class might be affecting the centered alignment.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).